Upgrading Firebase Cloud Messaging to FCM API HTTP V1 When Only Using Cloud Functions
I use Firebase Cloud Functions to send a notification using FCM when a new post is detected in Firebase Firestore.  I am upgrading an older app to Firebase Cloud Messaging API HTTP V1 because the legacy API is now disabled by Google.  The errors in my log on the deprecated API pointed me to these instructions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1.  But those instructions don't seem to address how to migrate when using Firebase Cloud Functions (I don't POST, etc.  I just call admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload) after I set up the tokens and payload.  FCM does the rest.
Are there any instructions for migrating when only using Cloud Functions?

I finally figured it out.  I was trying to change the service accounts in my Firebase account to solve the problem.  But the problem was that the Node.js syntax was deprecated.  Instead of calling:
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)

I had to use the new syntax and call:
admin.messaging().send(message)

and create a message object like this (I will change my payload to simplify it):
const message = {
    "notification": {
        "title": payload.notification.title,
        "body": payload.notification.body
    },
    "apns": {
        "payload": {
            "aps": {
                "alert": {
                    "title": payload.notification.title,
                    "body": payload.notification.body
                },
                "sound": "default",
                "badge": 1
            }
        }
    },
    "token": token
};

There's more information here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#example-notification-message-with-platform-specific-delivery-options
And for the apns properties, go here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/generating-a-remote-notification
Some of this information is in the migration documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#update-authorization-of-send-requests
But I didn't see where it showed the deprecated command sendToDevice was changed to send.

Google Firebase documentation is horrendous. Thanks for figuring it out. I am facing the same problem. Will definitely try your solution and post the result.
